# Reasons not to use abstract class instead of interface?

Tags: f#

I'm considering using an abstract class with all abstract members instead of an interface in order to avoid explicit interface implementation boiler-plate code. So instead of

```
type IMyInterface =
    abstract Name : string
    abstract Text : string

type MyClass() =
    member __.Name = "name"
    member __.Text = "text"
    interface IMyInterface with
        member this.Name = this.Name
        member this.Text = this.Text
```

I'd have

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type MyAbstractClass() =
    abstract Name : string
    abstract Text : string

type MyClass() = 
    inherit MyAbstractClass()
    override __.Name = "name"
    override __.Text = "text"
```

Any words of caution or implications I should be aware of here?

Comment: If you're making a decision between an interface and an abstract base class, you might also consider using both.  Provide an abstract base type that implementers can *choose* to inherit from, and have it implement an interface.  Then, accept references to the interface, rather than the ABC.  This won't work in every scenario (e.g. your code actually needs code that is in the ABC to exist on every concrete implementation, and can't accept an alternate implementation), but often can be a good idea.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham - Excellent suggestion! I'm trying this approach and so far it is working out very well, giving the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only thing that you should be aware and make a conscious decision is a class can inherit from only one class but implement many interfaces.

---

Apart from that, some recommendations on using Abstract classes or Interfaces:

> - If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component, create an
>     abstract class. Abstract classes
>     provide a simple and easy way to
>     version your components. By updating
>     the base class, all inheriting classes
>     are automatically updated with the
>     change. Interfaces, on the other hand,
>     cannot be changed once created. If a
>     new version of an interface is
>     required, you must create a whole new
>     interface.
> - If the functionality you are creating will be useful across a wide
>     range of disparate objects, use an
>     interface. Abstract classes should be
>     used primarily for objects that are
>     closely related, whereas interfaces
>     are best suited for providing common
>     functionality to unrelated classes.
> - If you are designing small, concise bits of functionality, use
>     interfaces. If you are designing large
>     functional units, use an abstract
>     class.
> - If you want to provide common, implemented functionality among all
>     implementations of your component, use
>     an abstract class. Abstract classes
>     allow you to partially implement your
>     class, whereas interfaces contain no
>     implementation for any members.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28vs.71%29.aspx

Personally, I feel these recommendations are spot on. Especially **Interfaces, on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.** is a very important point.

Comment: Right, thanks - that one just popped in my mind too. Definitely a biggy.

Comment: There is no technical reason an interface cannot be changed, unless it is exposed via COM.  The .Net framework/languages let you.  As for versioning, it is considered a bad practice to make breaking changes on a public library interface, unless there is a really good reason, but the same recommendation would apply to abstract base types, i.e. adding additional abstract members.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the .Net framework/languages let you"

Answer (score 4):

Stephen,

Only one, the most basic, and obvious... An interface allows for alternate implementations; if the "published well know type" is an abstract class you cannot later provide *any* alternatives... So the downside is you're limiting your future options; the upside is that (depending in how many inheritors there are) you could save a lot of boiler plate code.

If you're really really sure there ARE no other valid implementations then go the abstract class. If not then stick to the interface.

And I suppose you COULD do both... and I guess that'd give you most-of-the-best of both worlds.

Cheers. Keith.

PS: manojlds is right, of course ... and soooo much more sucinct ;-)

Comment: I think using interfaces limits future options more than abstract classes. If you ship an interface, you cannot later change it if your requirements change, because any change is a breaking change. Abstract classes are much more flexible, as you can add virtual members, and adjust the internal implemention, provided the public abstract methods don't change their signatures.

Comment: Mark, You have a "valid" point, it's just not, IMHO, a very "important" one. In my experience it's MUCH more common to need "a variant of an existing class"; verses "needing to add a method to an existing PUBLISHED interface". Quite simply; once an interface reaches the publication stage it IS set in stone; otherwise you wouldn't be publishing it, now would you?

Comment: Requirements can change after publication, more than anyone would like. Consider if you expose a plugin interface and later find out you need it to do more than it was doing. The solution when using an interface is that you need to create a new interface, and you're then stuck with maintianing multiple plugin architectures, where with an abstract class, that problem doesn't exist, because the new features can be added as virtual methods. I've had this problem several times. I've also seen this several times in various open source projects. Can't think of any off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 2):

In abstract class, you can implement some common behavior of all the sub classes.

In your interface design, you may want to have a method call other method to accomplish some compound task. For instance, `predictAll(Instance array)` may use `predictSingle(Instance)` and provides a default implementation for all sub classes. If you use interface, you need to implement `predictAll` in all subclasses.

But this point is not a big deal as the multiple inheritance one. I prefer interface more than abstract class.

Interface also keeps your design sallow.

One more point:
Interface encourages more *functional* code than abstract class. Typeclass in Haskell is a more powerful Interface.