# Why do I need to explicitly implement interface members, instead of benefiting of the "background" inheritance of an abstract class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface, abstract-class, member

As per title, and just to deeper understand the reasons, why does in c# interface forces you to manually implement the its members, whereas abstract class doesn't?

I found [Reasons not to use abstract class instead of interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768543/reasons-not-to-use-abstract-class-instead-of-interface), but it seems to cover just part of the answer exhaustive.

```
  public abstract class Bar
  {
    public int MemberA {get;set;}
    public string MemberB {get;set;}
  }

  public interface IBar
  {
    public int MemberA {get;set;}
    public string MemberB {get;set;}
  }
```

Implement this is fine:

```
  public class Foo1 : Bar
  {
  }
```

Implementing this raises a compile error:

```
  public class Foo2 : IBar
  {
  }
```

Error:

> 'Foo2' does not implement interface member 'IBar.MemberA'
>
> 'Foo2' does not implement interface member 'IBar.MemberB'

Comment: Abstract class forces you to implement its _abstract_ members the same way interface does. It's just class in your example doesn't have any abstract members, so nothing to implement.

Comment: Yes, I see, but if members are not marked `abstract`, it automatically implements them. Why is this not possible with interfaces?

Comment: It does not automatically implements them. They are inherited as usual, since they are already implemented in base class. Even if class is abstract - it can still implement members as usual, just as regular class. That's actually main difference between abstract class and interface - abstract class can contain members with implementation while interface cannot.

Comment: Ok, got that. So, to double-check, an abstract class without any abstract member, in its simplest form, is behaving as a regular class, right?

Comment: Yes, except you cannot create instance of that class (cannot do `new Bar()`). So except is quite rare scenarios - abstract class without abstract members is kind of useless.

Comment: You are asking for multiple inheritance.  No, that is a feature that was intentionally left out of the .NET design, a class can have only one base class.  MI has tricky issues, the "deadly diamond of death" is particularly infamous.  Not an issue with interfaces since you don't inherit anything.

Comment: Interfaces are like a contract. If a class implements one, it is committed to implement the feature(s) indicated by that interface. Because at runtime imagine if you had this line `IList myCustomList = methodThatReturnsCustomList()`, myCustomList being a class you designed. Imagine you did `myCustomList.IndexOf(whatever)`. That would give you an error if you didn't implement IndexOf in your class. A class subscribed to an interface GUARANTEES that there will be an implementation of every method defined by the interface, so you shouldn't be afraid to call any interface methods.

Comment: @NicodeOry That is completely understandable. What I don't get is why does an interface miss the feature - that abstract classes have - of defining "non abstract" members. It would have been useful to have an interface that distinguish between abstract and non abstract members, like an abstract class does. With the benefit of inheriting from multiple interfaces tough.

Comment: Because if you 1. need non-abstract members, why not use an `abstract` class? And 2. if interfaces provided that feature, it would kind of defeat their purpose: giving developers the freedom to implement their solution. Imagine there was a non-abstract method `IndexOf` in `IList`. It certainly wouldn't work with your custom list because the interface doesn't know anything of your implementation. And, as it is not abstract, you wouldn't be able to change it! It just wouldn't fit for the purpose of interfaces. By the way, just to clarify, all interface members are `abstract` and `public`.